# How to implement all types of array methods with react useState?

Tags: reactjs

I want to know how to make an `useState` to array and perform all the array methods with react `useState`, specially `push`, `pop`, `splice`, `includes`, `indexOf`. Which will be reactive.

I am making an accordion.

```json
{
    "options": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "HELP & INFORMATION",
            "option": [
                "Help",
                "Track order",
                "Delivery & returns"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "ABOUT SLEORPELS",
            "option": [
                "About us",
                "Career at SLEORPELS",
                "Corporate responsibility",
                "Investors' site"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "MORE FROM SLEORPELS",
            "option": [
                "Mobile and SLEORPELS apps",
                "SLEORPELS Marketplace",
                "Gift vouchers",
                "Black Friday",
                "SLEORPELS x Thrift+"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Where user can click options title `options.title` and it will expand each option `options.option`. So, I want to add each option id to an useState array, and when user click on an option, I want to push that id to that useState array, also set condition to JSX if the clicked id includes the useState it will expand. Also, some more logic.

But, I can't use  `push`, `splice`, `includes`, `indexOf` with the useState. Thats why I want to know how to use these methods with useState.

Comment: Please clarify your question. `useState` is a function. If you want your *state* to be an array, just put an array in it - it's that simple. If that is not what you are meaning, please update your question with more details

Comment: updated please see.

Comment: I think you're missing the idea behind how to useState, you don't push to state etc.  you first apply your array methods to the array you're fetching or manipulating and then you set to state.

Comment: But, that will be not reactive. I need reactive functionalities.

Comment: I tried in Redux and its working perfectly. But not with useState. So, can you tell me what is the purpose of useState?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate